# Can't get UTF-8 Special Chars to Correctly Write to MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I am creating a PHP script run from the command line on a typical LAMP stack (L = OS X) and am having a lot of trouble getting special chars to record properly in the database.

This script scans a directory recursively and inserts complete path into a MySQL database table. I've done a lot of research into how to get special chars to write to MySQL but they show up as `?` chars.

Here is the code:

```
<?PHP
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '--USER--', '--PASSWORD--');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(!mysql_select_db("files")) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== FALSE;
}

function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()) {
  $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $key => $value) {
            $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
            if(startsWith($path,'/Volumes/Macintosh HD/')) {
                    unset($files[$key]);
            } else if(!is_dir($path) && !startsWith($value,'.') && startsWith($path,'/Volumes/')) {
                    $results[] = $path;
                    $query="INSERT IGNORE INTO files (path,dir) VALUES ('$path','0')";
                    mysql_query($query);
            } else if(is_dir($path) && !startsWith($value,'.') && startsWith($path,'/Volumes/')) {
                    getDirContents($path, $results);
                    $results[] = $path;
                    $query="INSERT IGNORE INTO files (path,dir) VALUES ('$path','1')";
                    mysql_query($query);
            }
    }
    return $results;
}


$directory='/Volumes'; 
$files=getDirContents($directory);
sort($files);
print_r($files);

?>
```

The problematic path is:

```
/Volumes/Mac Stadium Shuttle 1/DIG2008060702/files/Susan-Jürgen.dvdproj/Contents/PkgInfo
```

Notice the umlaut char in `Jürgen`. When the script prints all of the files in the array the `ü` shows up correctly.

If I add a line to the PHP script to print the `mysql_query()`, the following is returned:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO files (path,dir) VALUES ('/Volumes/Mac Stadium Shuttle 1/DIG2008060702/files/Susan-Jürgen.dvdproj/Contents/PkgInfo','0')
```

Again the `ü` shows up correctly.

From the MySQL command line client, I `SELECT` this path:

```
mysql> select * from files where path like '%susan%';
```

...and the response:

```
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------+------+---------------+
| ID     | path                                                                                                                                                                  | dir  | google_id | md5  | deleted_local |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------+------+---------------+
| 644990 | /Volumes/Mac Stadium Shuttle 1/DIG2008060702/files/Susan-Ju?rgen.dvdproj/Contents/PkgInfo                                                                             | 0    | NULL      | NULL | 0             |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------+------+---------------+
```

...notice the `ü` in Jürgen shows up as `u?` (Ju?rgen)

I have worked to make sure that:

- that php.ini has the default charset as UTF-8
- the default charset of the table is utf8
- the DB connection is defined as a utf8 connection

I added `phpinfo();` near the top of this script (after `ini_set()`) and run it from the CLI. `default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8` shows up in the response.

After the DB is connected in the script, I added `echo mysql_client_encoding($link);` and the script printed `utf8`.

Also, I ran:

`mysql> show variables like 'char%';`

response:

```
 +--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
 | Variable_name            | Value                                                  |
 +--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
 | character_set_client     | utf8                                                   |
 | character_set_connection | utf8                                                   |
 | character_set_database   | utf8                                                   |
 | character_set_filesystem | binary                                                 |
 | character_set_results    | utf8                                                   |
 | character_set_server     | utf8                                                   |
 | character_set_system     | utf8                                                   |
 | character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.6.24-osx10.8-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
 +--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
 8 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT The structure of the table is:

```
 mysql> DESCRIBE files;
 +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | ID            | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | path          | varchar(510)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
 | dir           | enum('0','1')    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
 | google_id     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | md5           | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
 | deleted_local | enum('0','1')    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
 +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
 mysql> show create table files;
 +-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
 +-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | files | CREATE TABLE `files` (
      `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `path` varchar(510) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
      `dir` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '0',
      `google_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
      `md5` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted_local` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `path` (`path`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=961879 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
  +-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the table? It should be something like this `CREATE \`my_table\` (...) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: @Axalix Just added the SHOW CREATE TABLE output to main question above...thanks

Comment: Okay, I think you should separate the problem; it's either MySQL or PHP or both. Begin with MySQL: in the MySQL console try to make insert with that symbol and then select. Lets see if it works. If doesn't, we'll just focus on MySQL first. When I run this on my machine `insert into files(`path`) values ('Jürgen'); select * from files;` it returns *Jürgen*

Comment: all your columns use latin1, in particular your path column

Comment: I failed to mention that i did try to do an `INSERT` from the MySQL CLI client as you described, complete with the umlaut, and I was able to successfully `SELECT` it from the database with the umlaut. Which is puzzling, because the column is explicitly defined as Latin1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in your second edit, the path column has the latin1 charset, even though the table defaults to utf8.  Maybe you've got in this state by altering an existing table?

Try `ALTER TABLE files MODIFY path VARCHAR(510) CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Comment: latin1 is fine for words like *Jürgen* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-we-sets.html

Comment: This worked. `ALTER TABLE files MODIFY COLUMN path varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci UNIQUE;` The strange thing is that as @Axalix mentioned, Latin1 works fine with Umlauts. I wonder if it was because I had UTF-8 explicitly defined in php.ini and Latin1 on the column in the database? I also had the default charset for the table (not the column) set to UTF8.

Comment: @EwanMellor yes, I did set the default charset on the table after it was created.

Comment: Notice how the _default_ did not override the _existing_ `latin1` setting.

Comment: @axalix: latin1 is fine for Jürgen, but not if the PHP code is trying to insert UTF-8!

Answer (score 0):

1.set collation type of you database table field to utf8_unicode_ci

2.change in meta tag.

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

3. you can use echo utf8_encode($value);  in your page.